# Android Source Repo GPG public key not found

Tags: android, repository, gnupg, openpgp

I am running Linux Mint 14 and trying to download the android source. I followed the instruction for setting up the environment and when I was trying to get the source with repo, I got the following error.

```
...
 * [new tag]         v1.9.4     -> v1.9.4
 * [new tag]         v1.9.5     -> v1.9.5
 * [new tag]         v1.9.6     -> v1.9.6

object e76efdd7b342577c40aa271fa5ded9d66a783a9b
type commit
tag v1.12.4
tagger Conley Owens <cco3@android.com> 1380645867 -0700

repo 1.12.4

gpg: Signature made Tue 01 Oct 2013 09:44:27 AM PDT using RSA key ID 692B382C
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
error: could not verify the tag 'v1.12.4'
```

I've tried importing the public key from the instruction, try generating my own GPG keys, as well as symbolic linking the directories ~/.gnupg and ~/.repoconfig/gnupg both ways and I still get the same error. I also tried to deleting the ~/.repoconfig and ~/.gnupg and still no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Tried alot of different solutions mentioned everywhere: delete the repoconfig dir, import a key, git tag -v 1.12.4

can't wrap my head around

Answer (score 28, accepted):

i found a solution here:
http://www.marshut.com/wrrts/repo-release-1-12-4.html

> Sorry, I realized today that we didn't upload the newest version of
>   the launcher.  I'll update the documentation.  For the meantime,
>   please use:
>
> curl http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
>
> chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
>
> sha1 e197cb48ff4ddda4d11f23940d316e323b29671c
>
> If verification errors persist, you can blow away (or move) your
>   ~/.repoconfig dir to ensure the new public keys are imported.
>
> Sorry for the trouble everyone!

Comment: seems that repo 1.12.4 was only released a few hours ago

Comment: Seconding (thirding?) this. Replaced the installed version (and B2G version) of repo with this and things are back up and running.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the ~/bin and ~/bin/repo ownership.

If the owner is different your login (ex root:root), then you can see the above error.

Regards,
DS Son

Answer (score 0):

Using curl to update the repo utility did not fix this issue for me. I ended up doing the following:

```
$sudo apt-get install repo
$rm -rf ~/.repoconfig
$gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 692B382C
```

The above commands install repo utility to /usr/bin/repo, remove your .repoconfig file, and then install the missing key.

If your repo init command failed once, you should also remove the .repo folder before running repo init again.

Then, run your repo init command using /usr/bin/repo in place of just repo. When you do a repo init, it likely utilized the repo version located at ~/bin/repo not /usr/bin/repo. As an example, I ran the edited command as follows and all worked:

```
$/usr/bin/repo init -u https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/le/le/manifest.git -b [branch] -m [manifest]
```

Solution here was using a different version of repo. In my case, the one from apt-get worked but not the google link one. This was run on Ubuntu 16.

Answer (score 0):

This below solution worked for me. First delete the repo u installed with the bin directory.

```
rm -rf ~/bin
```

Then delete config file with the below commands.

`rm -rf .repoconfig/ rm -rf .gnupg/` (if available)

Then install the repo with the below commands.

```
sudo apt-get install repo
```

Then to install the signature run the below commands.

```
repo init
```

This will download the required signatures.

That's it, Run the `repo init -u <manifest url> -b <release> -m <manifest file>...`

`repo sync` it will start the sync.

Experimented on Ubuntu version: 18.04