# "gpg: Can't check signature: No public key" upon initializing a repo from code aurora

Tags: android, linux, git, repository, gnupg

I'm trying to run the following git repo command

```
repo init -u git://codeaurora.org/quic/le/le/manifest.git -b release -m [manifest xml] --repo-url=git://codeaurora.org/tools/repo.git --repo-branch=caf-stable
```

but I keep seeing the following gpg error:

```
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
fatal: cloning the git-repo repository failed, will remove '.repo/repo'
```

I tried to follow the steps as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19126958/12497236) to no avail

```
curl http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo

chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This below solution worked for me.
First delete the repo u installed with the bin directory.

```
 rm -rf ~/bin
```

Then delete config file with the below commands.

`rm -rf .repoconfig/ rm -rf .gnupg/` (if available)

Then install the repo with the below commands.

```
sudo apt-get install repo
```

Then to install the signature run the below commands.

```
repo init
```

This will download the required signatures.

That's it, Run the `repo init -u <manifest url> -b <release> -m <manifest file>...`

`repo sync` it will start the sync.

Experimented on Ubuntu version: 18.04

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this and found out you need to have the right gpg key in the ~/.repoconfig folder

Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/63125058

But put the key in right place.

```sh
mkdir -p ~/.repoconfig/gnupg/
GNUPGHOME=~/.repoconfig/gnupg/ gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 692B382C
```

Comment: running the second command errors out @ `--keyserver: command not found`

Comment: I tried the solution that's linked in your response and I was able run the `repo init` command but does that mean i'd have to use `/usr/bin/repo` for every repo command I need to run?

Comment: after repo init, I tried running `repo sync` and now it complains how I should be using python 2.6 - 2.7 instead...tried `/usr/bin/repo` as well but it gives out `ValueError`

Comment: Oops. I messed up my command. It it for gpg, which I have fixed now.

Comment: Try starting over and remove the --repo-url and --repo-branch args. I also had issues with the caf-stable and it worked for me without them.

Comment: are you implying there are issues with caf-stable and even repo url?

Comment: In short yes. It works for some of my colleagues, but not me, so maybe it depends on the version of python or the host operating system.

Comment: what python version are you using? When I tried your trick, I'm now getting a syntax error  `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: Yes, I got that too. I found that if using the codeaurora repo that you have to use python2.

Comment: great answer, thanks. I had to use a different keyserver though, that one seems to be down. `keyserver.ubuntu.com` or `pgp.mit.edu` worked for me

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to locate the CAF key and download it; the following should work.
Install repo from -> https://source.android.com/setup/develop#installing-repo

Drop the  `--repo-url=git://codeaurora.org/tools/repo.git --repo-branch=caf-stable` from your `repo init` command.

Comment: Works! drop that line.

Comment: This works, thanks! So, what if a specific branch is required? How to deal with that?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by specific branch. If you mean different Android versions then it’s better to re-init the repo with the new manifest.

Comment: The list of manifests is available on this page -> https://wiki.codelinaro.org/en/wiki-la/release